# Socket io. on('connection') creates an infinite loop

Tags: webpack, socket.io, webpack-dev-server

I am learning socket.io.
Following the tutorial I created a simple server using express and webpack.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const app = require('express')();

const config = require('./webpack.config.local');

const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const compiler = webpack(config);

// Set up the server to use webpack middleware
app.use(
  require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
  historyApiFallback: true,
  }),
 );

// We need hot reload too
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user is connected', socket.id);
});

// Server Listening
server.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
   console.log(err);
}
});
```

in the index.html I add this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-2.0.3.js"></script>
  <script>
const socket = io();
</script>
```

When I start the server the "user is connected" gets printed with an infinite loop, instead of just one. I have tried several tutorials but keep getting the same error.
I have the client and the server packages at the same version, but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.
[image]

Comment: I am using the same version of the packages for server and client. 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have no idea what happened, I changed port and it started working.
I have now went back to port 3000 and is working properly, not sure what really was happening but apparently has nothing to do with the code.